# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified When useing shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, apache, sudo, shell-exec

I have a php page that is trying to run a service restart using:

`$list=shell_exec('sudo /sbin/service NetworkManager restart');`

I needed to edit my sudoers file to let this happen.  Thus:

`#Defaults    requiretty`

and

`apache  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:     /sbin/service`

When that failed, as a test I ran:

`apache  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:     ALL`

I have run a shell_exec without the sudo command:

`$list=shell_exec('whoami');`

`echo $list;`

This returned "apache" as expected.  So I ran:

`$list=shell_exec('id');`

`echo $list;`

This returned  “uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),10(wheel)”

I checked the permissions of the files against a working system that is doing the same thing and they matched up.  After that just for testing sake I changed all file permissions to 777.  Still nothing.  In the apache error log I get the line "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified".  As I understand it that applies to the #Defaults requiretty line in the sudoers file but as stated that has been commented out.  I have done a bit more testing with it and my current entry in the sudoers file is:

`#Defaults    requiretty`

`ALL     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:   ALL`

I know not to run the server this way as it is a huge security risk but at this point I am at a total loss for what is locking me down.  Selinux is off all permissions are 777 and the ownership of files matches a working system I have.   With all of this and all possible security I can think of turned off I still have the “sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified” line in my /var/log/httpd/error_log every time.  The output of:

`$list=shell_exec('sudo echo "yes"  2>&1 ');`

`echo $list;`

Is also “sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified”?
I could really use some help on this one.  I have read every article for 4 google pages on this every way I can think to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my setup is a little different (I'm not trying to achieve it without a password), I use this in the sudoers file:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) ALL
Defaults:apache !requiretty
```

I then run things as:

```
echo '{password}' | sudo -S {command}
```

Comment: Doesn't the apache ALL=(ALL) ALL leave you exposed to attack?  One of the goals of my project is to minimize attack vectors.  I can see how this would work but I don't think it is quite what I need.

Answer (score 2):

From command prompt run

`sudo visudo`

Then go to the last line of the file and add the following line:

`%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: <Your-Command-Here>`

Hope this works!